# Update Dataframe1 based on condition with dataframe2 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my sample Dataframes and my expected result. How can I get the expected result. I tried using loop
for i in range(len(df2)):
for x in range(len(df1)):

and using if condition to compare column values and assign with .at method but getting
KeyError: 0 error

Df1

| Index | acn | name | dob | Insert | Update | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6946 | THAPA | 25-04-1982 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 7012 | SEKE | 14-07-1966 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 5824 | SEKE | 14-07-1966 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 6946 | JOHN | 25-04-1982 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Df2

| Index | acn | name | dob | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6946 | JOHN | 25-04-1982 | IKO7 |
| 1 | 5824 | SEKE | 14-07-1966 | GGF1 |

Expected Result

| Index | acn | name | dob | Insert | Update | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6946 | THAPA | 25-04-1982 | NaN | NaN | Create |
| 1 | 7012 | SEKE | 14-07-1966 | NaN | GGF1 | NaN |
| 2 | 5824 | SEKE | 14-07-1966 | GGF1 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 6946 | JOHN | 25-04-1982 | IKO7 | NaN | NaN |

How do I achieve this. Appreciate your help

Comment: Where does the `Create` value in the `New` column come from? Also, how `Update` column has been changed?

Comment: Based on conditions, like below
if (
            df1.at[i,"acn"] == df2.at[x, "acn"]
            and df1.at[i, "name"] == df2.at[x, "name"]
            and df1.at[i, "dob"] == df2.at[x, "dob"]
        ):
          
          

            df1.at[i, "Cont Insert"] = df2.at[i, "id"]

        if (
            df1.at[i, "name"] == df2.at[x, "name"]
            and df1.at[i, "dob"] == df2.at[x, "dob"]
        ):
            

            df1.at[i, "ACR Insert"] = df2.at[i, "id"]
   
  else:
    df1.at[i, "New"] ="Create"

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani  Thanks for ur response,  trying to populate 
Insert Update, New columns in df1 Based on  conditions above.

Answer (score 0):

Try merge, using `on` and `how` arguments:

```py
(df1.merge(df2, on=["acn", "name", "dob"], how="left")
      .drop(columns=["Insert","Index_y"])
      .rename(columns={"id":"Insert","Index_y":"Index"}))
```

##### Output

| Index_x | acn | name | dob | Update | New | Insert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6946 | THAPA | 1982-04-25 00:00:00 | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 7012 | SEKE | 1966-07-14 00:00:00 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 5824 | SEKE | 1966-07-14 00:00:00 | nan | nan | GGF1 |
| 3 | 6946 | JOHN | 1982-04-25 00:00:00 | nan | nan | IKO7 |

Comment: Was to be achieve this as below
for i in range(len(df1)):
     for x in range(len(df2)):
            if (
            df1.at[i,"acn"] == df2.at[x, "acn"]
            and df1.at[i, "name"] == df2.at[x, "name"]
            and df1.at[i, "dob"] == df2.at[x, "dob"]
        ):
            df1.at[i, " Insert"] = df2.at[i, "id"]
        if (
            df1.at[i, "name"] == df2.at[x, "name"]
            and df1.at[i, "dob"] == df2.at[x, "dob"]
        ):
          df1.at[i, " Insert"] = df2.at[i, "id"]
 else:
  df1.at[i, "New"] ="Create"

Comment: And second loop to remove the redundant values
for i in range(len(df1)):
    if df1.at[i,'Insert']==df1.at[i,'Insert']:
        
        df1.at[i,'Insert']=np.nan
        df1.at[i,'Con']=np.nan
        
    if pd.isna(df1.at[i,'Insert']) and pd.notna(df1.at[i,'Insert']) and pd.notna(df1.at[i,'Con']):
        df1.at[i,'Con']=np.nan

Serves the purpose, but keen to know if there's better way to achieve the same result.

Comment: @PDitta Thank you for coming back to this. It would be best if you could add your code to your question because comments usually are not meant to be for code snippets and I am having a hard time reading the code you wrote here. Thank you.